# I did a multivariate linear regression however the results are not what I expected

Tags: r, regression

I'm working on a personal project trying to model the Electricity consumption of a furnace, using R.

After creating my code I get this results for my model:

```
     R2_adj    N_Test       N_trained_data   E_relative   RMSE     
     0.1022      1104                 2593      0.03979   23.22kwht
```

My R2_adj is not great, however the model can somewhat precisely predict the output of electricity is this correct? If it is, how do I explain it?

The first image is the distribution of the data
[image]

The second image is the distribution of Errors and its average error
[image]

The last image is the real consumption cs the consumption predicted by the model.
[image]

I would appreciate greatly your help

I don't know if the model can be useful

Comment: Hard to investigate fully without a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/at/76995406/5010685)

But for starters, what is happening if you remove the one large outlier?

Comment: What exactly is your question?